# How to add current time stamp to test result in Codeception

Tags: php, automation, report, automated-tests, codeception

How to add current time stamp to Codeception Reports?
My Main aim is to keep all the run results,which currently I am not able to do as Result for all the run for Acceptance test are generated with same name i.e.acceptance.html

Comment: What command do you use to run codeception and generate reports?

Comment: php codecept.phar run --html <resultfile.html> acceptance

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the file name in your command,
so make your command more dynamic, like this: `php codecept.phar run --html result-$(date '+%FT%T').html acceptance`

Output:
`- HTML report generated in file:///.../tests/_output/result-2016-06-22T15:00:03.html`

The actual command that you have to use depends on your shell.

Comment: I am getting error  [Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]
 Suite '+%FT%T').html was not loaded after executing the command      php codecept.phar run --html result-$(date '+%FT%T').html acceptance

Comment: What shell are you using? run  echo $0

Comment: its printing $0                                                              E:\codeceptiondemo>echo $0
$0

Comment: oh, you are running it on windows, I can't help.

Comment: this is a correct answer actually, you just need to tune it to windows  php vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept run acceptance --xml name-%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%
time:~6,2%.xml     OR use logrotate monolog based extension for codeception in case your goal is to prevent rewrite